# Streaming radio ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, audio-streaming, internet-radio

Hello i'm searching for a good guide on how to implement a radio .mp3 stream in my app.
I have messed around with the matt gallagher tutorial "Streaming and playing an MP3 stream". And had it working in ios4 (also with background playing) but then i wanted to use it in ios5 and had a lot of errors. (because of the ARC) I've heard that there are other ways to implement a .mp3 through the AVPlayer class.

Does someone know a simple implementation or example which i could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using non-arc code in an arc-enabled project you can specify which files are non-arc and everything will work as expected. Just add the "-fno-objc-arc" flag to these files.